Error making a CV.pdf with cyrillic characters: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
I am trying to generate a CV with some text in russian, here's a snippet:
\UseRawInputEncoding

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*0.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0.5}{*1}
\titleformat*{\section}{\titlerule\smallskip\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries\lsstyle\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\itshape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\sffamily\lsstyle\footnotesize PAGE \thepage{} OF 2}

\setlist[itemize]{left=0pt..2em,itemsep=0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}

% skipping contacts section for this question

\section{Languages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Английский \hfill C1
        \item Русский \hfill Native
    \end{itemize}
    
\section{Опыт работы}

% rest of the document with sections still in english, that were not causing any issues

\end{document}

I have tried to use pdflatex CLI & Texworks GUI for this, but every time I am getting an error:
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (��).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.46 \section{Опыт работы}

Which is odd, because there is no error processing \item Английский \hfill C1 & \item Русский \hfill Native.
So, how do I fix it? And which packages do I really need to specify? Later on in the document I am using {multicols} & {itemize} as well. People online show that some packages can cause incompatibilities with Cyrillic characters & cryptic error messages.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...


Remove \UseRawEncoding
charter doesn't support Cyrillic
tgadventor doesn't support Cyrillic
inputenc can be omitted if the file encoding is UTF-8
you should likely tell LaTeX to use A4 paper

The issue is in \uppercase: you should use \MakeUppercase.
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
%\usepackage{charter}
%\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype}
%\usepackage{soul}% What for?
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.8in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*0.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0.5}{*1}
\titleformat*{\section}{\titlerule\smallskip\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\itshape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\sffamily\lsstyle\footnotesize PAGE \thepage{} OF 2}

\setlist[itemize]{left=0pt..2em,itemsep=0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}

% skipping contacts section for this question

\section{Languages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Английский \hfill C1
        \item Русский \hfill Native
    \end{itemize}

%\section{Опыт работы}
\section{Опыт работы}
% rest of the document with sections still in english, that were not causing any issues

\end{document}

Anyway, if your CV is mostly in English, you should define it as the main language and segregate the Russian parts within the otherlanguage* environment.
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel}
%\usepackage{charter}
%\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype}
%\usepackage{soul}% What for?
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.8in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*0.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0.5}{*1}
\titleformat*{\section}{\titlerule\smallskip\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\itshape}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\sffamily\lsstyle\footnotesize PAGE \thepage{} OF 2}

\setlist[itemize]{left=0pt..2em,itemsep=0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}

% skipping contacts section for this question

\section{Languages}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \foreignlanguage{russian}{Английский} \hfill C1
  \item \foreignlanguage{russian}{Русский} \hfill Native
\end{itemize}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
\section{Опыт работы}

[text in Russian]

\end{otherlanguage*}

% rest of the document with sections still in english, that were not causing any issues

\section{Other things in English}

[text in English]

\end{document}


About the fonts: you should find font families that support Cyrillic.

I suspect that your TeX file isn’t actually being saved in utf-8 (I’ve seen this before, where the inputenc didn’t match the actual encoding used when saving the file).
To fix the error you’re getting: Assuming your intent is to use utf-8, first make sure that the file is actually being saved with utf-8 encoding. Then:

Probably remove the UseRawInputEncoding. This appears to be a backwards compatibility feature you don’t want when using utf-8 — see here
Unless you’re using some pretty old software, you should be able to remove the inputenc line, since utf-8 has been the default for TeX since 2018 (as described in the link just above)


The points in this answer are true in general, but they are not the cause of the error in this question, which was the use of \uppercase vs. \MakeUppercase as described in the other answer.

How to make sure that file is indeed saved in UTF-8?

It depends on what software you’re using, but text editors will generally have either an encoding option to choose when saving the file, or have an encoding setting in a preferences menu (or something similar) that controls what encoding is used for all save actions. On Linux, you can check the encoding of a file after it has been saved using the  enca utility.

On Windows 10, Notepad will show you its best guess of the encoding of the opened file (down in lower-right corner of the window)
